# Mixing MongoDB query types (and, or)

Tags: mongodb

I am using MongoDB to store information on coffees and I am having problems with a query.

My document structure is:

```
{ _id: "Thailand Bok", tags: ["Strong", "Smooth", "Dark"] }
```

I am trying to create query that allows me to search either on the name or tags.

So given that a query string may be "Thailand Bok" or ["Strong", "Smooth"] I want to search for requests that either contain the _id or each tag.

If I were thinking in SQL terms it may be something like this:

```
"WHERE `_id` like 'Not present%' OR ("Strong" IN `tags` AND "Smooth" IN `tags`)"
```

The query I have so far is:

```
{ 
    $or: [
      { _id: { $regex: '^Not present', '$options': 'i' } },
      { 
          $and: [ 
              { tags: 'Strong' }, 
              { tags: 'Smooth' } 
          ]
      }
    ]
}
```

edit: correct a mistake in the query and clarified that it should work either if the _id matches OR the tags match

Comment: how is that going for you? do you need the `'` around the `$and`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$and is only supported in version MongoDB 2.0+ I was using 1.8.2

Answer (score 5):

You query seems allright except for using curly braces instead of square braces for $or.

```
{$or: [
  {_id: {$regex: '^hailand', $options: 'i'} }, 
  {'$and': [
       {tags: 'Strong'}, 
       {tags: 'Smooth'}
   ]}
]}
```

Works just fine.

Comment: Sorry that was a copy mistake. I have tried your query and it highlights my issue. When I copy yours directly ^hailand I get no search results. But if I use ^Thailand I do get search results. 

The outcome I am trying to get to is that you can match the name or the tags.

Comment: That's strange, because when i run this query - i get the result:  
---
> db.items.find({$or: [{_id: {$regex: '^hailand', $options: 'i'} }, {'$and': [{tags: 'Strong'}, {tags: 'Smooth'}]}]})  
---
{ "_id" : "Thailand Bok", "tags" : [ "Strong", "Smooth", "Dark" ] }

Comment: ... ah, the answer is I'm an idiot :) $and is only valid in 2.0+ I am using 1.8.2. Sorry.